Нужно ли препроцессить текст в машинном обучении при использовании готовой модели
При создании моделей машинного обучения чтобы качество ее было выше обычно применяются различные техники препроцессинга - токенизация, стоп-слова, лемматизация и.т.д. Причем современные инструменты типа spaCy могут дать возможность глубокого анализа, вплоть до коренных словв, например для слова "Кошка" он может предложить коренное слово "Кот", а не "Окошко"(которое побуквенно будет ближе к слову кошка).
Мой вопрос заключается в следующем, если я создал модель машинного обучения для текстовой мультиклассовой классификации, которая очень сильно обработана препроцессингом, не нужно ли для того, чтобы эта модель корректно работала проводить такой же препроцессинг и при работе с моделью?
Приведу пример. Пусть мы разрабатываем модель, которая исходя из текста комментария относит его к различным категориям. Предположим часть обучающей выборки после препроцессинга выглядит следующим образом:
  Сэмпл         |     Класс 

Кот шерсть серый    |     Животные. Коты
При этом очевидно предполагается, что пользователь будет писать комментарий типа "У моего котика такая серая шерстка, просто чудо!". Моя гипотеза заключается в следующем: если мы этот запрос пользователя перед передачей ее на вход готовой модели машинного обучения предварительно прогоним через тот же пайплайн препроцессинга, и получим вместо той фразы, что было написано фразу "кот серый шерсть чудо", не приведет ли это к росту качества данной модели?

Даю универсальный ответ, даже безотносительно конкретики вашего вопроса.
При использовании моделей машинного обучения должна быть в точности такая же подготовка данных (препроцессинг), как и при обучении модели. Если вы не будете готовить данные так же как при обучении, у вас на выходе модели будет вообще неизвестно что. И неправильные предсказания могут быть, и ошибки. Потому что модель ожидает специально подготовленные данные в определённом формате. Если вы ей скармливаете что-то другое, как минимум от этого ухудшается качество, а как максимум модель может вообще отказаться работать.
С текстами всё тоже самое, да. Особенно с текстами. Но вообще это универсальный принцип машинного обучения.
В вашем примере скорее всего получится, что модель просто не знает, что такое "котика" и что такое "шерстка". Она этих слов просто не распознает, потому что она их не видела при обучении. Она видела только слова "кот" и "шерсть". А те слова, которые вы ей скормили теперь, она их просто не знает и ничего по ним предсказать не сможет.
Ещё раз резюмирую. Процесс предобработки данных - необходимый этап в машинном обучении, он должен быть абсолютно одинаковым и при обучении модели и на этапе использования модели. Вообще с нейросетями там есть некоторые дополнительные нюансы, но в целом лучше железно придерживаться этого правила.
P.S. Например, библиотека FastText при обучении учится не только на словах из предоставленного ей текста, но и на отдельных буквах текста и их сочетаниях. Поэтому она может лучше работать, чем более простые модели, даже на тех словах, которые она не видела при обучении. Вот она возможно "котика" и "шерстку" распознает правильно. Но я бы на это не полагался.

Спасибо большое за развернутый ответ! Я свой вопрос писал по собственным ощущениям от прочтения большого количества материалов по многоклассовой или бинарной классификации, где как раз часто проводится усечение обучающего набора до лемм, но при этом проверка проводится на сырых данных. Видимо в этом примере это срабаывает по причине, что там находятся наиболее близкие слова. Ваш комментарий полностью соответствует моим умозаключениям.

"но при этом проверка проводится на сырых данных" это очень-очень странно, если действительно так. Может быть там препроцессинг всё же куда-то встроен в пайплайн модели, просто не сильно заметен? Ну то есть брать для проверки действительно нужно сырые данные, но при этом препроцессинг данных должен обязательно быть перед работой собственно модели.
